# Ubuntu: main monitor stays black

Tags: dual-boot, msi

I have an MSI 2QE Ghost Pro laptop with 2 hard disks, 1 SSD and 1 SATA. I have Windows 10 installed on the SSD and Ubuntu 14.04 on a partition of the SATA.

I have no issues with the windows partition. Whenever I boot into ubuntu, though, my laptop screen stays black. Its not a black light, it just as though the laptop screen just doesn't turn on. Ubuntu functions normal though. I've tried connecting an external monitor from the HDMI port and that monitor works fine. Using that I can also see that my laptop monitor is detected and I can even use it. It just stays black. Has anyone some idea why this might be happening?

I've tried updating my graphics card drivers but that didn't help. I'm not very experienced with Ubuntu and so am not sure what else to do.

Comment: Probably your laptop monitor has some problem? You should get it diagnosed